# Add a stroke on top of a layout

Tags: java, android

I have the following XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke
        android:width="0dp"
        android:color="#CCFFFFFF" />
    <solid android:color="#55FFFFFF" />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="0dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp" android:bottomRightRadius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

which produces the following:

[image]

How do I modify the code so there is a black line on the top like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add above the text and below the shape in xml file this code

```
   <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000000" />
```

Comment: It's `LinearLayout`, so it should be okay I am guessing. I will test it out.

Comment: It gave an extra space and did not come out as expected but I did not downvote :/

Comment: You can remove the extra spaces by maintaining the padding and margin of other views ... maybe the above view has bottom layout margin .. and you could also reduce the size of the height for example 0.5dp

Comment: I ended up using RelativeLayout inside the LinearLayout and it worked out :)

Answer (score 1):

You should do what with [nine-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) or insert View widget with height 1dp (or more)  and black background above this TextView.

Answer (score 1):

when the color of the top layer IS NOT semi-transparent, there is a fast, versatil, and clean, to add borders to a view, with layerlist drawable. 
Probably you couldnt use it in your case, but it this will be handful to somebody else who reach this question

for this, you create an xml file in you drawable folder, called border.xml with this content:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
      <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle">
         <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp" />

                <solid android:color="#000000" />


        </shape>
   </item>
   <item  > 
      <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle">
             <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
   </item>

</layer-list>
```

Then in your layout, you use

```
android:background="@drawable/border"
```

with this you have a way to quickly add borders, to one, or more sides of any view.

Comment: you are rite, i didnt realize he has an alpha in the color! i wont delete the post since it can be useful to somebody else that reach this question.

Comment: And you don't need to do that, but you should accent that